# Windows 8 Internet Explorer 11 proxy automation script

Tags: proxy, internet-explorer, windows-8.1

Similar to this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/17976/how-to-switch-proxy-settings-via-script), I'd like to change my proxy settings using a script. However, it fails. When I am behind the proxy, IE does not connect to the internet. Here I try the first solution from [craig](http://www.craigjconsulting.com/proxypac.html):

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) 
{ 
 if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "myactualip", "myactualsubnetip")) 
  return "PROXY proxyasshowninpicture:portihavetouseforthisproxy_see_picture"; 
 else 
  return "DIRECT"; 
}
```

This script is saved as proxy.pac in c:\windows and my configuration is* in LAN settings:
No automatically detected settings,
yes, use automatic config script: file://c:/windows/proxy.pac
No proxy server.

So, what am I doing wrong?

---------------- update --------------

However, when I set up a proxy in my LAN configurations:

```
IE -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings 
check: Use a proxy Server for your LAN
Address: <a pingable proxy> Port: <portnr>
```

everything is fine for this environment. [Now I try a simpler script like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    return "PROXY <pingable proxy>:<portnr>; DIRECT";
}
```

With a configuration described above** I am not able to get through the proxy.

Comment: Are you sure myIpAddress() is returning what you think it is?  In my experience it acts very buggy on systems with more than one network interface. For example it miss-reports the address sometimes on laptops with a wired and wireless connection.

Comment: @Zoredache I will test it. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: @Zodredace: I added a test without myIpAddress(). However, the script does not do what it is supposed to do. However, I also do not know how to test this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally [this page lead me to my solution:](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/10/11/web-proxy-configuration-and-ie11-changes.aspx)

```
file://-based proxy scripts are deprecated in IE11.
```

There are some temporary registry hacks given, but I was not able to get my scripts to work with regedits. Finally I [set up a local IIS server](http://www.ehow.com/how_2069183_install-localhost-server-windows.html)

```
Windows Start - "Control Panel." - click "Programs" link - "Turn Windows Features On or Off." 
Check the box labeled "Internet Information Services." Click "OK."
```

and moved my *.pac javascript file with the content

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    return "PROXY <proxyIP>:<proxyPort>; DIRECT";
}
```

into inetpub\wwwroot.

Afterwards I checked "Use automatic configuration script" in IE -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings. Use the \inetpub\wwwroot\scriptFilename.